# Can we run a bash script from a repo?

Tags: bash, bitbucket, sh

I am at beginner level. I am not sure if this is feasible or not. I have a bash script on bitbucket repo which does some kind of setup. To run that bash script I have to download that locally and run the .sh file. Is there any way I can run the script through bitbucket repo without downloading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll always need to download the file (i.e: retrieve it from the server), but you can produce a pipline to retrieve-and-execute in one. The simplest would be:

```sh
curl ${url} | bash
```

You'll need to locate the URL that presents the raw file (rather than the HTML web page). For BitBucket this will look something like below. You can substitue `${commit_id}` for a branch or tag name instead.

```
https://bitbucket.org/${user}/${repo}/raw/${commit_id}/${file}
```

---

Beware however that this often causes raised eyebrows from a security point of view, especially if retrieving the file via HTTP (rather than HTTPS), as you're basically running unknown code on your computer. Using `sudo` in this pipeline is even more concerning.

The user needs to be prepared to trust whatever is stored in the repository, so make sure that you only allow trusted users to push (or merge), and make sure that you review changes to the file in question carefully.

---

You should also be aware that when running a script like this (equally for `bash ${file}` or `bash < ${file}`), the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) will not be respected - it will just be seen as a comment and ignored.

If, for example you script begins as below (`-e` to exit on error, and `-u` to handle undefined variables as an error) then these flags will not be set.

```sh
#!/bin/bash -eu

# ... body of script ...
```

When "*executing*" the file directly (i.e: `chmod +x ./my_script.sh`, `./my_script.sh`), the kernel process the shebang and invokes `/bin/bash -eu`... but when executing the script via one of the above methods, the `bash` invocation is in the pipeline.

Instead, it is preferable to set these flags in the body of your script, so that the method of execution doesn't matter:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -eu

# ... body of script ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Attie

Comment: No problem! If it answered your question, please feel free to resolve your question by accepting my answer.